# Sumar un dia pero a una hora especifica PHP

Tags: php

Buenos dias saludos desde Peru tengo una funcion que suma un dia es para un sistema de Hotel por lo cual debe salir al siguiente dia siempre al mediodia entonces si yo alquilo una habitacion a las 3 pm de hoy la salida sera al medio dia de mañana este es la linea que se encarga de sumar un dia pero debe ser a las 12 del mediodia siempre

```
$fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$fecha + 1 day")); //Aumente en un dia
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Sumas un día a la fecha sin hora y luego añades la hora ya que siempre es la misma.

```
$fecha = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha." + 1 day")). " 12:00:00";
```